# Favicon for iPhone Safari Favorites?

Tags: iphone, ios, html

How do you get the favicon to display for the Favorites screen on Safari? Here is what I see now -

**Example:**

- Site - [www.justinreina.com](http://www.justinreina.com)
- Public repo - [www.github.com/justinmreina/portfolio](http://www.github.com/justinmreina/portfolio)

[image]

what gives? I have tried PNGs of all sorts and a crazy favicon, to no luck. This works for everything else

**Question:**

How do you create a favicon for the Apple iPhone's Favorite screen in Safari?

Comment: did the answer not resolve the favicon problem?

Comment: Hi @JashJacob, no it does not! Thank you for the help this makes sense but does not work I am confused. Here was my latest work, hosted to justinreina.com & erisdar.com right now - https://justinreina.com?favicon

Comment: I do not see where you have mentioned the code I have mentioned in the head section. Just write the <link> code as in and add the reference image as mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following ***apple-touch-icon*** for Safari to pick up the image as a reference in Favorites tab. This has been implemented since iOS 1.1.3

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Reference : [Link](https://webhint.io/docs/user-guide/hints/hint-apple-touch-icons/)

Comment: By the way, Google and Microsoft have different syntax. You should add HTML syntax for all of them (they can, however, point to a single image file - or maybe a few different sizes).